# Initual weight of neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hi I am studying about Neural Network and after reading through the code of [Convolution Neural Network](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) written by dennybritz. In the embedding layer, he initialed the weight of this layer to learn word embedding by normal distribution

`W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), name="W")`

However in convolution layer, he used truncated normal to initial the weight or neural nodes.

`W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")`

Why did he use two different distribution? I did a little research and find this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) but not sure is it the reason.Can anyones suggest anythings?

Thanks